# Вывести топ 3 ключ-значения словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список с `n` словарями (допустим их будет 4):

```
array = [{'Mary': 16707}, {'James': 86266}, {'Jacob': 34467}, {'Mary': 64137}]
```

Мне нужно сделать один словарь, в котором будет топ-3 по значению из списка `array`.

```
output = {'James': 86266, 'Mary': 64137, 'Jacob': 34467}
```

Так как словари не сортируются, хотел бы получить подсказку, как лучше всего решить данную задачку. Спасибо

Comment: Вам нужно вывести отсортированый словарь? В котором значения будут распологаться по убыванию или просто пройти по списку и достать три максимальных значения?

Comment: Значения которые, будут распологаться по убыванию.

Comment: Используйте тот же список словарей, только с тремя топовыми записями

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы отсортировать список словарей по убыванию значений в парах `(ключ, значение)`:

```
>>> sorted_pairs = sorted(((k, v) for d in array for k, v in d.items()),
...                       key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
>>> sorted_pairs
[('James', 86266), ('Mary', 64137), ('Jacob', 34467), ('Mary', 16707)]
```

Обычные словари неупорядочены в Питоне, поэтому чтобы получить упорядоченный словарь, содержащий три ключа из `sorted_pairs`, соответствующие наибольшим значениям, можно использовать [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

output = OrderedDict()
for k, v in sorted_pairs:
    if k not in output:
        output[k] = v
        if len(output) == 3:
            break  # enough
# -> OrderedDict([('James', 86266), ('Mary', 64137), ('Jacob', 34467)])
```

Обратите внимание, что было бы неправильно использовать: `output = OrderedDict(sorted_pairs[:3])` вместо явного цикла с `if len(output) == 3:` так как ключи могут повторяться в `sorted_pairs`, но не могут повторяться в словаре, поэтому в этом случае `output` может *меньше* `3` ключей содержать, если просто `3` пары передать, и к тому же с возможно ме́ньшими значениями чем надо (так как последнее значение для одного того же ключа побеждает: `{'a': 3, 'a': 1} == {'a': 1}`).

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

TOP_COUNT = 3


def target_key_getter(elem):
    # Понятие "первый ключ" для обычного словаря в общем довльно бессмысленное
    try:
        return next(iter(elem))
    except StopIteration:
        return None

array = [{'Mary': 16707}, {'James': 86266}, {'Jacob': 34467}, {'Mary': 64137}, {}]

desc_dict = OrderedDict()
for elem in sorted(array, 
                   key=lambda e: e[target_key_getter(e)] if target_key_getter(e) is not None, 
                   reverse=True):
    target_key = target_key_getter(elem)
    if target_key not in desc_dict:
        desc_dict[target_key] = elem[target_key]

for key, value in list(desc_dict.items())[:TOP_COUNT]:
    print(key, value)
```

Вы должны использовать [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), для того, чтобы сохранить порядок, потому что в обычном словаре порядок не гарантируется. Также вы должны проверять наличие ключа в новом упорядоченном словаре, чтобы исключить замещение большего значения меньшим.

Также из-за того, что "первый ключ" для словаря не имеет смысла (в нем нет первых, нет порядка вообще, [порядок может меняться от запуска к запуску](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522626/hash-function-in-python-3-3-returns-different-results-between-sessions)), то вы можете использовать кортежи или словари вида:

```
{
    "name": "Mary",
    "value": 123456
}
```

с ними будет намного легче работать и код будет выглядеть корректней.

Comment: [можно упростить код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658277/23044), если список словарей в виде коллекции пар представить.

Answer (score 2):

Учитывая, что все словари содержат только одну пару ключ-значение, их более удобно представлять в виде последовательности кортежей:

```
array = [{'Mary': 16707}, {'James': 86266}, {'Jacob': 34467}, {'Mary': 64137}]

updated = (next(iter(d.items())) 
           for d in array)
```

Далее можно удобно отсортировать и передать желаемое количество элементов в конструктор словаря:

```
import operator
top3 = sorted(updated, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:3]
result = dict(top3)
```

Выражение `sorted(updated, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:3]` можно записать проще, если использовать функцию [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) из стандартной библиотеки:

```
from heapq import nlargest
top3 = nlargest(3, updated, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
result = dict(top3)
```

Если вам дополнительно хочется сохранить порядок итерации, можно использовать [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from heapq import nlargest
top3 = nlargest(3, updated, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
result = OrderedDict(top3)
```

---

**Функция [`operator.itemgetter(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)** создаёт функцию, которая для объекта `lst` вызовет `lst[n]`, т.е.

```
operator.itemgetter(2)('abcd') == 'c'  # т.к. 'abcd'[2] == 'c'
```

**Функция [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)** принимает на вход последовательность и ключ, по которому сравниваются значения, например,

```
sorted([[3, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]], key=lambda lst: lst[1])
```

вернёт список списков, отсортированных по второму элементу

```
[[2, 1, 3], [3, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2]]
     ^          ^          ^
```

И как я уже выше указывал, `lambda lst: lst[1]` можно заменить на `operator.itemgetter(1)`.

По умолчанию сортировка выполняется в порядке возрастания, поэтому я передал дополнительный параметр `reverse=True`, чтобы получить обратный порядок сортировки.

Comment: ключи могут повторяться в разных словарях, поэтому `[:3]` в вашем коде может быть недостаточно, чтобы `len(result)==3` получить в итоге.

Answer (score 2):

Выбираем только большие значения из списка, по ним сортируем и строим топ 3

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from collections import OrderedDict

elements =[
{'Mary': 16707}, 
{'James': 86266}, 
{'Jacob': 34467}, 
{'Mary': 64137},
{'Alfa': 12137},
{'Mary': 2137}
]

dfs = {}  # временный словарь, для записей

for i in elements:  # разобрали список на элементы
    for key, value in i.items(): # словарь на ключ, значение
        dic_value = dfs.get(key)  # узнаем есть ли значение в словаре
        if dic_value != None:  # если нет, пропускаем
            # выбираем если больше, равное и меньше пропускаем
            if dic_value > value:
                value = dic_value
        dfs.update({key: value}) # записываем в словарь

# сотрировка словаря по значению, по убыванию
s = (OrderedDict(sorted(dfs.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)))
srez3 = list(s)[0:3] # срез, топ 3 без значений ['James', 'Mary', 'Jacob']

out = {}
for key_srez in srez3:  # в словаре находим значения ключей
    # вывод на экран, с разделителем :
    print (key_srez, ":", dfs.get(key_srez))

# James : 86266
# Mary : 64137
# Jacob : 34467
```

Изначальный вопрос был не точно сформулирован, поэтому дополнительный вариант с подсчетом суммы всех элементов, предпологается что значения должны складываться.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from collections import OrderedDict  # для сортировки словаря

elements =[
{'Mary': 16707}, 
{'James': 86266}, 
{'Jacob': 34467}, 
{'Mary': 64137},
{'Alfa': 12137},
{'Omega': 2137}
]

dfs = {}  # временный словарь, для суммирования записей

for i in elements:  # разобрали список на элементы
    for key, value in i.items(): # словарь на ключ, значение
        dic_value = dfs.get(key)  # узнаем есть ли значение в словаре
        if dic_value != None:  # если нет, пропускаем
            value = value + dic_value  # иначе суммируем значения
        dfs.update({key: value}) # записываем в словарь

# сотрировка словаря по значению, по убыванию
s = (OrderedDict(sorted(dfs.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)))
srez3 = list(s)[0:3] # срез, топ 3 без значений ['James', 'Mary', 'Jacob']

for key_srez in srez3:  # в словаре находим значения ключей
    # вывод на экран, с разделителем :
    print (key_srez, ":", dfs.get(key_srez))

# James : 86266
# Mary : 80844
# Jacob : 34467
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val = lambda dct: list(dct.values())[0]
sorted_array = sorted(array, key=val)

output = {}
for dct in sorted_array[-3:]:
  output.update(dct)
```

Comment: ключи могут повторяться в разных словарях, поэтому `[-3:]` в вашем коде может быть недостаточно, чтобы `len(output)==3` получить в итоге.  Попробуйте: `array = [{'a': 100}, {'a':99}, {'b':98}, {'c':97}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
output = {k: d[k] for e, d in enumerate(sorted(
    array, key=lambda d: next(d[k] for k in d), reverse=True)) for k in d if e < 3}
# output: {'James': 86266, 'Mary': 64137, 'Jacob': 34467}
```